# MongoDB ,Delete arrays c#

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, project

I have this model

```
    { "_id" : 133,
 "name" : "Gisela Levin",
"scores" : [ { "type" : "exam", "score" : 15.88727528055548 }, 
             { "type" : "quiz", "score" : 91.49884857295594 }, 
             { "type" : "homework", "score" : 16.56032169309347 },
             { "type" : "homework", "score" : 1.704262924559419 } ] }
```

i want to delete the less homework like this

```
{ "_id" : 133,
 "name" : "Gisela Levin",
"scores" : [ { "type" : "exam", "score" : 15.88727528055548 }, 
             { "type" : "quiz", "score" : 91.49884857295594 }, 
             { "type" : "homework", "score" : 16.56032169309347 } ] }
```

thats my class

```
class students2 {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
             public scorest[] scores { get; set; }

        }


 public class scorest
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public double score { get; set; }            
    }
```

thats my idea

searching all arrays, and then delete the lowest,but only show me one array by student

```
var query = await col.Find(x => x.name == "Gisela Levin").Project(Builders<students2>.Projection.Include(x => x.name).ElemMatch(x => x.scores, y => y.type == "homework")).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you have read the data into your c# variables, and want to filter the data you could use linq in the following way;

```
public static students2 FilterStudentScores()
    {
        var student = new students2
        {
            id = 133,
            name = "Gisela Levin",
            scores = new scorest[] { new scorest { type = "exam", score= 15.88727528055548 },
         new scorest{ type= "quiz", score= 91.49884857295594 },
         new scorest{ type= "homework", score= 16.56032169309347 },
         new scorest{ type= "homework", score= 1.704262924559419 }  }
        };

        double maxScore = student.scores.Where(s => s.type.Equals("homework")).Max(s => s.score);
        scorest[] filteredscores = student.scores.Where(s => !s.type.Equals("homework") || (s.type.Equals("homework") && s.score == maxScore)).ToArray();

        students2 filteredStudent = new students2
        {
            id = 133,
            name = "Gisela Levin",
            scores = filteredscores
        };
        return filteredStudent;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, and sorry about my english ... perhaps i am not beeing clear.... i am connecting at mongodb and i need to delete de lower score by student

Comment: So you want to delete the rows in the data base?

Comment: yes  this is the mongodb collection form    { "_id" : 133,
 "name" : "Gisela Levin",
"scores" : [ { "type" : "exam", "score" : 15.88727528055548 }, 
             { "type" : "quiz", "score" : 91.49884857295594 }, 
             { "type" : "homework", "score" : 16.56032169309347 },
             { "type" : "homework", "score" : 1.704262924559419 } ] } , so i want to delete   { "type" : "homework", "score" : 1.704262924559419 }